# Check if type is generic

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to implement a code analyser which takes as input another Java file. For each Variable Declaration, I want to check if the type that the variable belongs to is generic or not. Is there a simple way to do that?

For example, I would like for it to:

```
isGenericType("HashSet") -> true
isGenericType("int") -> false
```

I can possibly create a registry containing all generic types, but the problem with that would be if I implement a custom generic type, then I would have to update the registry each time. Is there some simple solution to this?

Comment: Do you want to identify types that have one or more type parameters in their declaration? Or to identify a generic use of a type? For example, as @manouti observes, HashSet is defined with a type parameter, but can be used in a raw manner. So do you really want a variable declaration using a raw HashSet to evaluate as generic?

Comment: No, thanks for pointing that out. I would only want to return true when HashSet is defined with a typed parameter.

Answer (score 6):

I think this is similar to what you are looking for:

It prints `true` for `java.util.HashSet`.

But `false` for `java.lang.Object`.

```
public class TestGenerics
{
    public static boolean isGenericType(String s) throws ClassNotFoundException
    {
        Class c = Class.forName(s);
        return c.getTypeParameters().length > 0;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException 
    {
        System.out.println(isGenericType("java.util.HashSet"));
        System.out.println(isGenericType("java.lang.Object"));
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer requires that the classloader for the code analyzer have access to all of the bytecode used by the program being analyzed.

Comment: This answer, while being short and simple, does not work for the custom types unless as @Erick G. Hagstrom pointed out it has access to the bytecode as well. I would want to ideally run this code analyser on the java source file itself as executables are IMO just bad!

Answer (score 6):

This will test by object, class or class name.

**Update:** Several revisions of this code based on helpful comments have provided some interesting test cases. However, ultimately an appropriate solution to the problem depends on precisely how the question is defined. Refer to earlier revisions and comments.

```
import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class GenericTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            new GenericTest().testAll();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }

        System.exit(0);
    }

    public void testAll() throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException
    {
        Object a = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        Object b = new HashMap();
        int c = 0;

        isGeneric(a);
        System.out.println("\n");
        isGeneric(b);
        System.out.println("\n");
        isGeneric(c);
        System.out.println("\n");
        isGeneric("java.util.HashMap");
        System.out.println("\n");
        isGeneric("java.lang.Integer");
        System.out.println("\n");

        isGeneric(new TestA());
        System.out.println("\n");
        isGeneric(new TestB());
        System.out.println("\n");
        isGeneric(new TestB<String>());
        System.out.println("\n");
        isGeneric(new TestC());
        System.out.println("\n");
        isGeneric(new TestD());
        System.out.println("\n");
        isGeneric(new TestE());
        System.out.println("\n");

        return;
    }

    public static void isGeneric(String className) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException
    {
        GenericTest.isGeneric(Class.forName(className));
        return;
    }

    public static boolean isGeneric(Object o)
    {
        return isGeneric(o.getClass());
    }

    public static boolean isGeneric(Class<?> c)
    {
        boolean hasTypeParameters = hasTypeParameters(c);
        boolean hasGenericSuperclass = hasGenericSuperclass(c);
//      boolean hasGenericSuperinterface = hasGenericSuperinterface(c);
//      boolean isGeneric = hasTypeParameters || hasGenericSuperclass || hasGenericSuperinterface;
        boolean isGeneric = hasTypeParameters || hasGenericSuperclass;

        System.out.println(c.getName() + " isGeneric: " + isGeneric);

        return isGeneric;
    }

    public static boolean hasTypeParameters(Class<?> c)
    {
        boolean flag = c.getTypeParameters().length > 0;
        System.out.println(c.getName() + " hasTypeParameters: " + c.getTypeParameters().length);
        return flag;
    }

    public static boolean hasGenericSuperclass(Class<?> c)
    {
        Class<?> testClass = c;

        while (testClass != null)
        {
            Type t = testClass.getGenericSuperclass();

            if (t instanceof ParameterizedType)
            {
                System.out.println(c.getName() + " hasGenericSuperclass: " + t.getClass().getName());
                return true;
            }

            testClass = testClass.getSuperclass();
        }

        return false;
    }

    public static boolean hasGenericSuperinterface(Class<?> c)
    {
        for (Type t : c.getGenericInterfaces())
        {
            if (t instanceof ParameterizedType)
            {
                System.out.println(c.getName() + " hasGenericSuperinterface: " + t.getClass().getName());
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public interface TestX<X> { }

    public interface TestY extends TestX<String> { }

    public class TestA implements TestY { }

    public class TestB<V> extends TestA { }

    public class TestC extends TestB<String> { }

    public class TestD extends TestA { }

    public class TestE extends TestC { }
}
```

The results of running the above code:

```
java.util.HashMap hasTypeParameters: 2
java.util.HashMap hasGenericSuperclass: sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl
java.util.HashMap isGeneric: true


java.util.HashMap hasTypeParameters: 2
java.util.HashMap hasGenericSuperclass: sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl
java.util.HashMap isGeneric: true


java.lang.Integer hasTypeParameters: 0
java.lang.Integer isGeneric: false


java.util.HashMap hasTypeParameters: 2
java.util.HashMap hasGenericSuperclass: sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl
java.util.HashMap isGeneric: true


java.lang.Integer hasTypeParameters: 0
java.lang.Integer isGeneric: false


GenericTest$TestA hasTypeParameters: 0
GenericTest$TestA isGeneric: false


GenericTest$TestB hasTypeParameters: 1
GenericTest$TestB isGeneric: true


GenericTest$TestB hasTypeParameters: 1
GenericTest$TestB isGeneric: true


GenericTest$TestC hasTypeParameters: 0
GenericTest$TestC hasGenericSuperclass: sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl
GenericTest$TestC isGeneric: true


GenericTest$TestD hasTypeParameters: 0
GenericTest$TestD isGeneric: false


GenericTest$TestE hasTypeParameters: 0
GenericTest$TestE hasGenericSuperclass: sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl
GenericTest$TestE isGeneric: true
```

Comment: This checks to see if the superclass is a ParameterizedType. OP wants to know if the class itself is "Generic" (which may mean parameterized, I'm not sure yet). Why not just use c instanceof ParameterizedType?

Comment: @ErickG.Hagstrom Good point. You're correct about 'getGenericSuperclass()', however, c instanceof ParameterizedType would result in a compile error against a raw Class<T>: 'Incompatible conditional operand types Class and ParameterizedType'. I revised my example to test based on number of generic parameters, as in the answer provided by euginioy. However, a complete solution might also test the superclass (see the case of TestC above, where is "not a generic" but its superclass is a generic).

Comment: Ok, good to know about c instanceof ParameterizedType not working. Makes sense to use the $ of type parameters. But if you want to test the superclass, don't you want to test the entire hierarchy (superclass of superclass, interfaces implemented and their supers)?

Comment: @ErickG.Hagstrom Well, this has certainly been illuminating. I am now in 100% agreement with you - reflection isn't giving the right answer, particularly in the case of java.lang.Integer.

Comment: Ah, the Comparable<T> interface implemented by java.lang.Integer. But Integer binds that T to itself when implemented. So I'm going to say that reflection isn't the problem here, it's the idea that supertypes need to be checked. We only need to check the type parameters of the Class itself, ignoring its supers.

Answer (score 5):

Even if `HashSet` can be generic, the type `HashSet` itself (without `<T>`) is a *raw type*. Therefore, I would go with the approach of scanning the actual type of the declared variable, maybe applying a regex on the type to see if the angle brackets exist:

```
isGenericType --> matches the pattern [a-zA-Z_\$][\w\$]*<[a-zA-Z_\$][\w\$]*>
```

If you want to strictly account for a valid identifer, you can check its definition in the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-Identifier):

> *Identifier:*
>
> > *IdentifierChars but not a Keyword or BooleanLiteral or NullLiteral*
>
> *IdentifierChars:*
>
> > *JavaLetter {JavaLetterOrDigit}*
>
> *JavaLetter:*
>
> > *any Unicode character that is a "Java letter"*
>
> *JavaLetterOrDigit:*
>
> > *any Unicode character that is a "Java letter-or-digit"*
>
> A "Java letter" is a character for which the method `Character.isJavaIdentifierStart(int)` returns true.
>
> A "Java letter-or-digit" is a character for which the method `Character.isJavaIdentifierPart(int)` returns true.

Comment: The regex should take into account that class names can contain digits 0-9, _ underscores, and $ dollar signs.

Comment: Should it not be, `[a-zA-Z_\$]+[a-zA-Z0-9_\$]*[\w]*<[\w]*[a-zA-Z_\$]+[a-zA-Z0-9_\$]*[\w]*>` ?

Comment: @MusicMaster My regex is not intended to be exactly accurate, just stating the idea.

Comment: My regex starts with `[a-zA-Z_\$]+` which indicates there must be at least one letter, dollar sign, or underscore first.

Comment: @MusicMaster Again, a regex may not be the best approach. An identifier can have some "special" Unicode characters.

Comment: First of all, why would your answer suggest regex if it is "not the best approach"? And also, I didn't think Java allowed Unicode characters in identifiers.

Comment: OK, my bad, Unicode characters are allowed. You are right.

Comment: This is more of a hacky solution and is indeed workable in most cases, but as @manouti has mentioned, it becomes difficult if we take into consideration the unicode characters to come up with a perfect regex! Thanks nonetheless!

Comment: @akhiljain If you want to strictly account for a valid identifer, you can check its [definition in the Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-Identifier).

Answer (score 3):

The other answers seem to be focused on using a regular expression or reflection, but what this seems to call for is a parser. So that's what I recommend you use.

As an example, Eclipse has their Java Development Tools (JDT) plug-in which provides you with all of the parse tools you'd need to do this right. All you'd have to do is ask the JDT to give you an Abstract Syntax Tree (AST) with bindings enabled. Whenever a variable is declared you'd get an ITypeBinding for the declared type of the variable, and another for the instantiated type (if the variable is instantiated in the declaration).

And ITypeBinding has methods that tell you whether it is generic, parameterized, etc.

You'll also get the type parameters, in case you need those.

There are other java parser options as well, but this is the one with which I am familiar.

=============================================

Specific results using the Eclipse JDT

Case 1: `HashSet<String> h1 = new HashSet();`

Case 2: `HashSet<String> h2 = new HashSet<>();`

Case 3: `HashSet<String> h3 = new HashSet<String>();`

As currently understood, the goal of this exercise is to recognize Case 1 as not generic (it is raw), and Cases 2 and 3 as generic (they have type parameters, though in Case 2 the type parameter is implied).

Looking solely at the nodes produced from `new HashSet...`

All three cases produce a ClassInstanceCreation instance.

Case 1 and Case 2 have 0 type arguments, while Case 3 has 1 type argument.

The ITypeBinding for Case 1 is marked raw, while for Cases 2 and 3 they are marked parameterized. **This constitutes success**, as we have a way of distinguishing between Case 1 on the one hand and Cases 2 and 3 on the other.

The ITypeBinding for Case 1 has 0 type arguments, while Cases 2 and 3 both have 1 type argument in the ITypeBinding. Note that Case 2 has 0 type arguments in the AST itself, but the binding has one type argument. This allows one to distinguish between an explicit type argument and the use of the diamond operator.

All of the information necessary to complete this task is readily available from the AST and bindings.

Now here's the bad news: the bindings are only available when the byte code is available, i.e. this isn't a simple text analysis exercise.

Comment: I actually tried using the Lombok parser to obtain an AST. But it seems that they do not have a separate node for the TypeParameters. Also, I basically wanted to distinguish between the following three types of instantiations:
`HashSet<String> h = new HashSet()`
`HashSet<String> h = new HashSet<>()`
`HashSet<String> h = new HashSet<String>()`

The parsers that I have looked at reduce the first two cases to the same representation in the AST

Comment: I updated the answer to show you what you can get from the ITypeBinding in the Eclipse JDT. Please note that the bindings are only available when the byte code is accessible, so is no better than reflection in that regard. But it is superior to reflection in that we can distinguish between a raw instantiation and one using the diamond operator.